# Java Errors: Need to declare a variable as final in actionPerformed, but I need it to change

Tags: java, swing, variables, timer, actionlistener

This has been solved by [Robin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076463/robin). Thanks Robin!

The idea behind what I want to do is make a timer that performs an action every X seconds, but X has to change between uses.

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
 try {
        final FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("timetest.log");
        final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        ActionListener task_performer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                critical_requests[0]++;
                try {
                    System.out.println("DEBUG: Critical Section requests: " + critical_requests[0] + "\n");
                    out.write("Critical Section request:\t" + critical_requests[0] + "\n");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "\n");
                }
                ((Timer)evt.getSource()).setDelay( 150 + (rand.nextInt(10) * time_unit ));
            }
        };
        new Timer(wait_delay, task_performer).start();
        System.out.println("Entering while loop\n");
        while(true) {
            if(critical_requests[0] >= 60){
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Close failed for some reason:\t" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
            //System.out.println("" + critical_requests[0] + "\n");    // Debug
            critical_requests[0] = critical_requests[0];    // Java is an insane language and it requires me to have this line here
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
local variable is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

I tried making some of them final, but then I can't change the values inside of the listener. Plus some of the variables don't make sense to make final (the BufferedWriter out, rand).

All 5 compiler errors are:
    local variable rand is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
one each for out, rand, and wait_delay, and two for critical_requests.

How can I reconcile this?

Comment: Why would it not make sense to make `out` and `rand` final? What effect do you think changing the value of `wait_delay` will have?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as well as the compilation errors.

Comment: Jon Skeet: I want to change the wait_delay after every call to actionPerformed so that there's a variable amount of time between each trigger.

So like the first time it waits for 15 milliseconds, the second time it waits for 20, third time 11 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code the problem is the `wait_delay` and the `critical_requests` variable.

1. There is no real need to change it inside the `ActionListener`. You will have to set it on the `Timer` again before it has any effect on the delay of the `Timer`
2. Creating a new `Timer` object each time you change the `wait_delay` variable will result in a lot of `Timer` instances, which each keep running as a `Timer` repeats by default. Only if you have called `setRepeats( false )` they will actually stop. Looking at your comment (which should have been part of the question), you want to update the delay of the `Timer`
3. If you really have to change the `critical_requests` variable inside the `ActionListener`, you can store it in a final array

So I would suggest to change your code to something like

```
final int[] critical_requests = new int[]{ 0 };
final Outputstream out = ...;
ActionListener task_performer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            critical_requests[0] = critical_requests[0] + 1;
            try {
                out.write("Critical Section request:\t" + (critical_requests[0]) + "\n");
                ((Timer)evt.getSource()).setDelay( 10 + (rand.nextInt() % 10) );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
};
Timer the_one_and_only_timer = new Timer( wait_delay, task_performer );
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have two options:

- Make it as a class field.
- Use another variable and assigned the old variable to it, somehting like:

```
ActionListener task_performer = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        int temp = wait_delay; // assuming wait_delay is final
        temp = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

make "wait_delay" non-local variable in method. Put it out of method definition.